# QuickBlox: how can you clean a group dialog, without deleting it?

Tags: chat, quickblox

The API gives the option of [deleting a dialog](http://quickblox.com/developers/Chat#Delete_dialog). Is it possible to clean a dialog (remove all messages) without deleting it?

Comment: Did you find any solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

There is no native way to delete all messages but keep the dialog, but there are two workarounds possible:

1) Write a script that will execute API calls to first retrieve messages of a particular dialog, and then delete these messages;
2) Delete manually via Quickblox admin panel.

Useful links:

[Retrieve messages](https://quickblox.com/developers/Chat#Retrieve_messages)

[Delete message](https://quickblox.com/developers/Chat#Delete_message)